# Final reference to an object when constructing it

Tags: java

Say I have a reference to some class and it is final like:

```
public final Mycalss ref;
```

and MyClass has several attributes (not final ones). Now when I construct MyClass object like this:

```
ref = new MyClass( some arguments);
```

Does it mean that other threads can safely see the content of Myclass since it is final referenced?

Comment: final means the object can not be re-referenced. since it components aren't final, it might change of value, though, depending on whether or not there are setters. Whether other threads can see your object, is not related to whether or not it is final.

Comment: It's safe as long as you don't modify the fields of MyClass. If you modify them then the guarantees of `final` won't be sufficient.

Comment: @assylias Yes - exactly.

Comment: What assylias means: if you modify them *after* you assign them to the final field. Modifying them before assigning them to the final field is safe. But you asked about "when constructing it" (in the title)  and "when I construct" (in the question), so in that case, it's safe.

Answer (score 4):

Making a reference `final` means once you assign an object to that reference, you cannot assign some other object to that reference.

But you can change the values of that same object even if the reference is declared as `final`.

Like :

```
public final Myclass ref;
ref = new Myclass();

//this is not allowed
ref = new MyClass();   //since you have already assigned an object to your final reference

//this is allowed
ref.setSomeProperty("abc"):
```

For answer on threading and final, see @Erwin Bolwidt answer.

Comment: It is incorrect. "making a reference final does not have relation with other threads accessing your object." Safe publication of references is one of the fundamental uses of the `final` keyword in Java. See my answer.

Comment: This does not answer the question: "*Does it mean that other threads can safely see the content of Myclass?*"...

Answer (score 2):

From the [Java Language Specification section 17.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5):

> The usage model for final fields is a simple one: Set the final fields
>   for an object in that object's constructor; and do not write a
>   reference to the object being constructed in a place where another
>   thread can see it before the object's constructor is finished. If this
>   is followed, then *when the object is seen by another thread, that
>   thread will always see the **correctly constructed** version of that
>   object's final fields*. It will also see versions of any object or
>   array referenced by those final fields that are at least as up-to-date
>   as the final fields are.

(My emphasis added)

This is part of the "Threads and Locks" section 17 of the JLS, of which also the Java Memory Model specification is part.

Yes, you are correct. This is a correct way to safely construct objects.

Comment: Yes.  But the OP asked if it was safe for different threads to change the (mutable) fields of the object - it is *not*.  You are guaranteed that all threads will see the same instance and which instance will not changed.  But you still need to synchronize any update to the contents of the object - probably by synchronizing on the object - if the application is to be properly thread-safe.

Comment: Where did the OP ask that? "Does it mean that other threads can safely see the content of Myclass since it is final referenced?" I think you misread something in the question.

Comment: Aside: the simplest technique is to ensure the object(s) shared between threads are completely immutable.  You can near always solve the same problem and achieve this - it isn't always easy (or natural) to do in Java however.

Comment: @Paul The OP asked "*Does it mean that other threads can safely see the content of Myclass*" and the answer is yes because using final guarantees safe publication. If you start mutating the fields of MyClass you do lose that guarantee.

Comment: @Erwin Boldwidt  Well, he said "see the content".  He also said the fields of the object are not final.  There is the strong implication that if they are not final, then they are subject to change - possibly from different threads.  Otherwise, why not make those fields final too?

Comment: @Paul that's the purpose of the `final` field. All fields inside the object referenced by the final fields are also memory-consistent. That's the last part of the quote: "It will also see versions of any object or array referenced by those final fields that are at least as up-to-date as the final fields are." Java has a very well thought out memory model.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt This is only true for initial publication. if the fields of MyClass are mutated after it is published (`i.e. after `final Myclass c = new MyClass(...)`, those changes won't be guaranteed to be visible from other threads...

Comment: @assylias Yes that's right. Since the OP said "*when I construct* MyClass object" is sort of thought that initial publication is the scope of the question, but if you take it further, than indeed you need to create another happens-before relationship with any thread that wants to have guaranteed visibility of changes.

Comment: The quote from the JLS doesn't apply in this case.  The fields of `MyClass` are not final.  If they are mutated by one thread there is no guarantee another thread will see the changes even through the reference `ref` is final.  Either `MyClass` should be made immutable OR access to its mutable instance needs to be synchronized.

Comment: @Paul please read the JLS carefully.MyClass is the "any object or array referenced y those final fields". Trust me, I know this spec well. We're talking about initial publication though, because that's what the OP asked about. If you are talking about subsequent updates, that's a different matter altogether.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt  Yes, I am very definitely talking about subsequent updates, as that seems to be implied by the fields of `MyClass` being mutable.  I agree you are correct by the letter of the JLS at the point of construction.  I'm thinking more about the potential for a hard-to-find bug when something actually does mutate one of the fields in `MyClass` that another thread is relying on.  (Either now - or when the code is later changed.  I've fixed a lot of broken multithreaded code.)

Answer (score 1):

As others said `final` means that only one assignment to this variable can ever occur. However, in multithreading environment, if thread A access the object before thread B made the assignemnt, thread A will see `null`. It means that thread A can see two different values of the variable.

Also, you should remember about [Memory Consistency Errors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/memconsist.html) - i.e. that changes made to on object by one thread may not be visible to the other thread. I would recommend to do some reading on synchronisation and `volatile` keyword - [this is a good place to start](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html).

Comment: Good point!  I was assuming - for no good reason - that `ref` was a member field of another object, and also that the assignment would happen in a constructor.

Comment: That's why IDE show a warning "leaking this in constructor" - other thread could see the object before it is fully constructed and could see nulls for variables which are final and never null.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make an instance of a class visible by all classes with its attributes being immutable, you should declare the attributes as private, not create any setters, and use the Singleton pattern (you can find it on google, basically the constructor of your class is private, in your class you have a field that will be static and be the only instance of your class, and you create a getInstance() method which is static and returns the current instance and/or instantiates it if it's null).

The class will look something like this :

```
public class A {
   private static A instance;

   private A() {}

   public static synchronized A getInstance() {
      if (instance == null) {
         instance = new A();
      }
      return instance;
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't see a problem with that if none of its attributes are ever modified, is there something I'm missing ?
Just add "synchronized" on the getInstance() method if that's what your pointing at, kinda harsh to downvote asap. Edited my OP.

Comment: It is because if thread T1 constructs A and T2 comes and call getInstance, it could see a non null reference pointing to a partially constructed object. Also I fail to see necessity of using a singleton - the OP never mentioned that he wanted a single instance of MyClass... And if `A` is mutable (which is the case) exposing it as a singleton is going to be a nightmare: any piece of code that accesses `instance` may make changes which will randomly affect other pieces of code....

Comment: I understand that, that's why I added the synchronized on the getInstance method. That being said if every attribute of A has 0 setters and is private, there's no way the object is mutable once it is instantiated. Whether or not he needs a singleton pattern or not is subject to discussion, I felt like he wanted to access a single instance of a class in the scope of his whole application in which case it makes sense.